# google speed mod

Tags: apache-2.2, google, mediatemple

hi i tried to install google speed mod on my (MT) DV server and i got this error while trying to restart the httpd can anyone help

```
Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_pagespeed.so into server: /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_pagespeed.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I followed this TUT http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv):Install_mod_pagespeed#Instructions to part 9 where you do phpinfo... did i need to do more im not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you installed a 32bit binary on a 64bit server.

You can verify yoru architechure by issuing the `uname -a` command. It will show something similar to:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 23 02:21:33 CST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The important part is the `x86_64` bit. What you want to do now is:

```
#rpm -e `rpm -qa | grep pagespeed`
#rpm -i https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-beta_current_x86_64.rpm
```

Everything should work then